# Open IE using Powershell on Windows Server 2012

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, iis, asp-classic

We have several Classic ASP applications that ultimately need to print a report to a printer from the web server.

I am using the input from the user to build the report on the server (server-side). I store it in an html file on the server.  Then I pass the filename and printername to a powershell script.  The powershell script is calling IE and printing the file.  Wonderful!  Not so quick!

On my PC it works great (I'm running IIS and so it should be mimicking a web server).

However, when I put it all on the web server the error I'm getting in my log is:

**Error number:** -2147024891

**Error description:** Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

**Error Source:** `$ie = new-object -comObject InternetExplorer.Application`

Is there an IIS setting or some other setting in Windows 2012 R2 that would cause this and changing it would cause it to work?

Powershell follows:

```
Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

$newline = [Environment]::NewLine
$FileName = $args[0]
$PrinterName = $args[1]
$Logfile = $args[2]
$strReturn = "0^Successful"

"Filename: " + $FileName
"Printer:  " + $PrinterName

#Send To named printer
try
{
#Change the Default Printer
(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName . -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Name='$PrinterName'").SetDefaultPrinter()

#Print a file from Microsoft Word (which can apply formatting changes)
$ie = new-object -comObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate($FileName)
while ( $ie.busy ) { Start-Sleep -second 5 }
$ie.ExecWB(6,2)

}
catch
{

    $strMessage = $error[0].Exception.Message
    $strHResult = $error[0].Exception.HResult
    $strLine = $error[0].InvocationInfo.Line
    $strReturn = "1^Error attempting to print report.^" + $strHResult + "^" + $strMessage + "^Line: " + $strLine
}
finally
{

    # garbage collection
    [gc]::collect() 
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()


    #exit $strReturn
}
    # write to a log file
    #  Log file time stamp:
    $LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy@hh:mm:ss"
    $LogRecord = $LogTime + "^" + $FileName + "^" + $PrinterName + "^" + $strReturn
    LogWrite $LogRecord

$strReturn
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly a permissions issue. You probably need to either:

1. Change the identity of the web app on the server to a user that has access to automate IE.
2. If it's already running as a specific user (not Application Identity), make sure that user has run IE interactively at least once.
3. Change the DCOM launch permissions so the app identity can open it.

I also suggest another possibility. Create a scheduled task that runs every minute which checks a directory (or something) for something to print, and print it.

The task has permission to do this. The web app gets permission to start the task. Less chance of the web app being exploited.